# PHP scws extention is not loaded by MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I have a problem about loading extension of PHP in MAMP:

I have compiled and installed scws.so (PHP extension for Chinese words segmentation) into folder '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions' together with other extensions like pgsql.so, etc.

Also, I've updated the php.ini under '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6' by adding 'extension=scws.so'.

If I issue command '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php -m' in console, I can see 'scws' is in the output list. But it has not been loaded after starting MAMP, also, I can not see 'scws' is listed with function phpinfo().

Could anyone help me about how to force the load of the new PHP extension? Why it is listed by 'php -m', but actually not loaded by MAMP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration for PHP called from web server is different from command line php. In `phpinfo()` check the path to the `php.ini` file that is being used and make sure that it is the same file that you edited to add the extensions.

Comment: There are two, one is '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf', and the other one is called 'Loaded Configuration File' which is  '/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini'. After I updated the second one ../MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini by adding extension, and restart MAMP, the updating in this php.ini is gone, and scws.so is not loaded. Do you know where I can update it?

Comment: @user2257731 I do not understand what you are saying - what do you mean by `After I updated the second one ../MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini by adding extension, and restart MAMP, the updating in this php.ini is gone, and scws.so is not loaded.`?

Comment: It turns out the actual php.ini used by MAMP is /Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources/php5.3.6.ini. After changing that file, scws works fine now.  Thanks for your inspiration!

Comment: strange why it didnt show up in phpinfo..however I am glad you figured it out!